# How to use a variable from one activity to another activity

Tags: android

I want to use a variable(answer) that I got from my code by calculating 3 numbers together on other activity, I want to calculate a new variable using the answer I got from the previous calculation on activity one in activity 2 . I tried to search on Internet but there isn't much about it , or i'ts all about passing a text value to another page and by displacing it . I somehow manage to get this idea right at the first time , but my emulator won't work.

this is my code , I hope I made it sensible .

Activity 1

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_male);

    age =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.age);
    height=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.heigth);
    weight =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.weigth);
    result =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

    eage=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.eage);
    eheight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.eheight);
    eweight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.eweight);


    calculate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    back =(Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
    next =(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);

    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            double n1=Double.parseDouble(eage.getText().toString());
            double n2=Double.parseDouble(eheight.getText().toString());
            double n3=Double.parseDouble(eweight.getText().toString());
            double ans=(90+4.8*n2+13.4*n3-5.7*n1);
            result.setText("Your BMR is "+ans);



        }
    });

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i=new Intent(MALE.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MALE.this, MALERUN.class);
            double n1=Double.parseDouble(eage.getText().toString());
            double n2=Double.parseDouble(eheight.getText().toString());
            double n3=Double.parseDouble(eweight.getText().toString());
            double ans=(90+4.8*n2+13.4*n3-5.7*n1);
            result.setText("Your BMR is "+ans);
            i.putExtra("answer",ans);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
```

Activity 2

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_malerun);
    calculate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    back =(Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
    next =(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
    result =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
    time=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.time);


    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (time.getText().equals(0));
            Intent i = getIntent();
            double[] n1=i.getDoubleArrayExtra("answer");
            double ans = (n1*1.2);



        }
    });







}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass data using `Intent`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("ANSWER", answer);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in Activity 2.class on Create

```
double answer = getintent().getDoubleExtra("ANSWER", 0.0);
```

Comment: I tried this before it won' work , because the value I want to put is the answer I got from calculating n1 ,n2 and n3 , I tried putting intent.putExtra("answer"，ans) , but it just shows error

Comment: You tried `getDoubleArrayExtra` but you pass only single double value so try `getDoubleExtra`

Comment: I put intent.putExtra("answer",ans) , the ans stands for the double ans=(90+4.8*n2+13.4*n3-5.7*n1); from my code  , and it says error from my second activity , it says operator * can't be applied to double[] , double

Comment: Change this `double n1=i.getDoubleArrayExtra("answer");
            double ans = (n1*1.2);` with this code `double n1=i.getDoubleExtra("answer", 0.0);
double ans = (n1*1.2);`

Comment: You can replace any double value with 0.0, You have to set some default value, thats why I write 0.0, Please mark answer as accepted if helped.

Answer (score 2):

best way:

in activity 1:

```
public static String myVar;
```

in activity 2:

```
String m=activity1.myVar;
```